# grpc server won't release memory, is there a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, grpc

I build a grpc server with c++ and find that its memory won't be released after several requests. memory increase first, and if I keep sending requests, the memory stay at a peak value. After I stop sending requests, memory won't be released or little memory released. what's wrong with my code, memory should be released soon or keep as catch buffer?

```cpp
class BaseCallData {
 public:
  BaseCallData(XFRProcessor *processor)
      : processor_(processor), status_(CallStatus::CREATE) {}
  virtual ~BaseCallData() = default;

  void Proceed() {
    if (status_ == CallStatus::CREATE) {
      status_ = CallStatus::PROCESS;
      Request();
    } else if (status_ == CallStatus::PROCESS) {
      NewCallData();

      //TODO
      OnRequest();

      Response();
      status_ = CallStatus::FINISH;
    } else if (status_ == CallStatus::FINISH) {
      delete this;
    } else {
      LOGGER_ERROR(Log::GetLog(), "wrong grpc status");
    }
  }

  template<class RpcReq, class RpcRes, class ReqData, class RspData>
  void WorkFlow(RpcReq &grpc_request,
                RpcRes &grpc_response,
                ServerContext &ctx,
                ReqData &request_data,
                RspData &response_data) {
    ErrorCode error_code = RequestReader::Instance()->ReadRequest(grpc_request, ctx, request_data);
    ReqTimer req_timer(request_data.log_id_, request_data.request_type_);
    if (error_code == OK) {
      error_code = processor_->Proceed(&request_data, &response_data, &req_timer);
      response_data.error_code = error_code;
      grpc_response = ResponseAssigner::Instance()->AssignResponse(response_data);
      if (OK == error_code) {
        req_timer.SetStatus(true);
      } else {
        LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(),
                    "[REQ:{}][LOG:{}] fail to run, err[{}]",
                    request_data.GetRequestType(),
                    request_data.GetLogId(),
                    error_code);
        req_timer.SetStatus(false, std::to_string(error_code));
      }
    } else {
      LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to read request, err[{}]", error_code);
      req_timer.SetStatus(false, std::to_string(error_code));
      grpc_response.set_error_code(error_code);
      grpc_response.set_error_msg(GetErrorMsg(error_code));
    }
  }

  XFRProcessor *GetProcessor() {
    return processor_;
  }
 private:
  virtual void NewCallData() = 0;
  virtual void Request() = 0;
  virtual void Response() = 0;
  virtual void OnRequest() = 0;
  enum class CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
  CallStatus status_;
  XFRProcessor *processor_;
};

class DetectCallData : public BaseCallData {
 public:
  DetectCallData(::xfr::XFRService::AsyncService *service, ServerCompletionQueue *cq, XFRProcessor *processor)
      : BaseCallData(processor), p_service_(service), p_cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_) {
    Proceed();
  }

  void NewCallData() override {
    new DetectCallData(p_service_, p_cq_, GetProcessor());
  }

  void Request() override {
    p_service_->RequestDetect(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, p_cq_, p_cq_, this);
  }

  void Response() override {
    responder_.Finish(response_, Status::OK, this);
  }

  void OnRequest() override {
    WorkFlow(request_, response_, ctx_, request_data_, response_data_);
  }
 private:
  ServerContext ctx_;
  ::xfr::XFRService::AsyncService *p_service_;
  ServerCompletionQueue *p_cq_;
  ::xfr::DetectRequest request_;
  ::xfr::DetectResponse response_;
  DetectRequest request_data_;
  DetectResponse response_data_;
  ServerAsyncResponseWriter<::xfr::DetectResponse> responder_;
};

class CompareCallData : public BaseCallData {
 ...
};

class MatchCallData : public BaseCallData {
 ...
};

class XFRServer final {
 public:
  XFRServer(const XFRServer &) = delete;
  XFRServer &operator=(const XFRServer &) = delete;

  XFRServer() {
    Init();
    builder_.AddListeningPort(address_, InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder_.RegisterService(&service_);
    builder_.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(max_receive_size_);
    builder_.SetMaxSendMessageSize(max_send_size_);

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_num_; ++i) {
      auto p_cq = builder_.AddCompletionQueue();
      v_cq_.push_back(std::move(p_cq));
    }
  }

  void Init() {
    auto grpc_config = hobot::vision::xfr::ServerConfig::GetConfig()->GetSubConfig("grpc");
    address_ = grpc_config->GetSTDStringValue("server_address");
    if (address_.empty()) {
      LOGGER_ERROR(Log::GetLog(), "fail to get server address: {}", address_);
      exit(0);
    }
    thread_num_ = grpc_config->GetIntValue("server_thread_count", 300);
    max_receive_size_ = grpc_config->GetIntValue("max_receive_message_bytes", 20971520);
    max_send_size_ = grpc_config->GetIntValue("max_send_message_bytes", 20971520);
  }

  ~XFRServer() {
    server_->Shutdown();
    //document shows that cq should always shutdown after server
    for (auto &cq : v_cq_) {
      cq->Shutdown();
    }
  }

  void HandleRpcs(ServerCompletionQueue *cq) {
    auto detect_processor = std::make_shared<DetectProcessor>();
    auto compare_processor = std::make_shared<CompareProcessor>();
    auto match_processor = std::make_shared<MatchProcessor>();
    new DetectCallData(&service_, cq, detect_processor.get());
    new CompareCallData(&service_, cq, compare_processor.get());
    new MatchCallData(&service_, cq, match_processor.get());

    void *tag{nullptr};
    bool ok{false};
    while (true) {
      if (!cq->Next(&tag, &ok)) {
        LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "Server stream closed, quiting");
        break;
      }

      if (ok) {
        static_cast<BaseCallData *>(tag)->Proceed();
      }
    }
  }

  void run() {
    server_ = builder_.BuildAndStart();
    for (auto &cq:v_cq_) {
      v_threads_.emplace_back(
          std::thread([this, &cq] {
            HandleRpcs(cq.get());
          })
      );
    }
    LOGGER_INFO(Log::GetLog(), "grpc server start working...");

    v_threads_.emplace_back(
        std::thread([&zk_register] {
          zk_register.KeepPublished();
        })
    );

    for (auto &t: v_threads_) {
      t.join();
    }
  }

 private:
  std::string address_;
  int thread_num_;
  std::vector<std::thread> v_threads_;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ServerCompletionQueue>> v_cq_;
  ::xfr::XFRService::AsyncService service_;
  std::unique_ptr<Server> server_;
  ServerBuilder builder_;

  int max_receive_size_;
  int max_send_size_;
};
```

Comment: Can you run it under valgrind or compile with some leak detection library?

Comment: There are like 3 raw `new`s and a single `delete this;`. Of course it's gonna leak all over the place. Use `std::unique_ptr` + `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @nwp the BaseClass will delete all its children

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok I will try it...

Comment: _@south_ You should follow @nwp's advice and use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for you advice,  I will follow the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

here may be one of the answer.
I didn't handle the state machine correctly.

```cpp
 while (true) {
      if (!cq->Next(&tag, &ok)) {
        LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "Server stream closed, quiting");
        break;
      }

      if (ok) {
        static_cast<BaseCallData *>(tag)->Proceed();
      }
    }
```

when `ok!=true`, object won't be deleted. so every time when I shutdown the client with 'ctl+c', memory leak.